# how to use fabricjs for synchronizing data between a and b client browers

Tags: fabricjs

how can use fabricjs to sync pencilbrush data  between a client and b client.

now i can use socket.io do that common shaps but pencilbrush can't do 
  my example code

```
    client a --send 
 canvas.on('object:modified', function(options){
            console.info("object modified",options)
           socket.emit('js_object_redraw', {id:data.target.id,object:data.target});

    },false);

  client b --recieve

 socket.on('client_js_object_redraw', function (data) {
        console.info("client_js_object_redraw:",data)
        console.info("data.target.type",data.object.type)
        var ele = canvas.getObjects()
        for (var i=0;i<ele.length;i++) {
            var cur_object = ele[i]
            if (data.id == cur_object.id){           

                canvas.remove(cur_object);
                draw_object_by_type(data)
            }
        }
});


 function draw_object_by_type(data){
    if(data.object.type=="rect"){
        draw_rect(data);
    }else if(data.object.type=="line"){
        draw_line(data);
    } else if(data.object.type=="triangle"){
        draw_triangle(data);
    } 
    ......
}

function draw_rect(data){
    var id =  data.id;
    var object = data.object
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        id:id,
        left : object.left,
        top :object.top,
        width : 60,
        height : 70,
        scaleX: object.scaleX,
        scaleY: object.scaleY,
        angle: object.angle,
        fill : object.fill
    });

    canvas.add(rect);
    return rect;
}
```

nodejs server:
     socket.on('js_object_redraw', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('client_js_object_redraw',data)

```
});
```

=================================================================

pencilBrush 
 I can do it syc data 
like :

when i draw line  i emit event to b

but i can't earse the line.
when i   clear line 
  like:
 var ctx = canvas.getContext();
        ctx.clearRect(x, y, 50, 50);

the next draw sharp ,the have remove line will show the canvas

how can i do that ,sync data between a and b client and can remove the sharp.

thanks,very much

Answer (score 0):

RacerJs is good option for Synchronize data between multiple clients here is complete example https://github.com/codeparty/racer